# defining subprojects in a deeply nested directory tree

Tags: gradle

how do I define sub projects in a nested directory tree where the sub-project folders are not immediate children of the root project

```
root
  lala
    A
  lulu
    B
```

Now I Want to add A & B as sub projects. If I do

```
//settings.gradle
include "lala:A", "lulu:B"
```

then also "lala" and "lulu" will be added as sub projects. However I only want to add A & B and nothing else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Gradle assumes that the physical directory layout follows the logical project hierarchy, but you can reconfigure it any way you like. For example:

```
include "A", "B"

project(":A").projectDir = file("lala/A")
project(":B").projectDir = file("lala/B")
```